# How to grep a file using search parameters from another file

Tags: bash, grep, for-loop

I am trying to use a file containing IP addresses as the basis for searching through a Cisco firewall configuration file.  Normally, I would use something like:

```
for i in $(cat ip.file); do grep $i fw.config; done
```

But doing that returns absolutely nothing.  If I put the above script into a file and execute it with the bash -xv flags, each line returns something like this:

```
+ for i in '`cat ip.file`'
+ grep $'1.2.3.4\r' fw.config  (each IP address is different)
```

grep 1.2.3.4 fw.config is exactly what I want to happen, but I get nothing back from this command.

I know of the grep -f option, but that also returns nothing.  I am not an experienced coder, so I might be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but you should always quote variables when they're arguments to a command. It's not a bad idea to use `--` to stop option processing when one of the arguments is a variable, too. `grep -- "$i" fw.config`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like `ip.file` is in DOS format and has `\r\n` line endings. Run `dos2unix` on it to convert to UNIX format. This will get rid of the errant `\r` carriage returns that are messing up `grep`.

By the way, you can use `grep -f FILE` to pass `grep` a list of patterns to search for. It will then do a single pass searching for any of those patterns.

```
# After doing `dos2unix ip.file'...
grep -f ip.file fw.config

# Or...
grep -f <(dos2unix < ip.file) fw.config
```

Comment: the `-f` approach also has the advantage that it interprets the search pattern as simple strings -- e.g. the dots in "1.2.3.4" will only match dots, not any character.

Comment: This was the answer.  The list of IP addresses was grepped from a dns zone file which I downloaded from my dns provider via a web browser.  I had no idea that it was in dos format.  Good catch.  After running dos2unix, grep -f worked as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

GNU grep,

```
grep -f ip.txt config
```

Its advisable also not to use for loop with cat. (If you do, you should change IFS to $'\n').  Use while read loop instead.

```
while read -r line
do
  ....
done <"ip.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(tr '\r' '\n' < ip.file); do grep $i fw.config; done
```